# Same element width or height as another one from different parent level

Tags: css

Is possible to set with CSS only, the same width or height as another one element in different parent level?

I don't think so, but I am interested if someone have some solution that surprise.
Of course with not using Javascript, and without making blank structure like source into target, and also without fixed sizes. Everything has to be responsive and clean.

## Example

```html
<div class="parent1"> <!-- flex box, that define all 3 children the same width -->
    <div id="child1-width">a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
    <div style="width: '#child1-width'"></div>
    <!-- <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div> Without this! -->
</div>
```

Comment: i dont understand ur question, could u pls share an image of what u want

Comment: Not with that HTML but with a common grandparent it might be possible by playing with CSS-Grid.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/VwMLraa?editors=1100

Comment: @Paulie_D it is partially good answer. But there should be still problem with more encapsulation or absolutely another HTML semantics. But thanx for inspiration